# WiX Adjust Install Path from user defined root folder

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I am using WiX toolset to write an installer for some plugins for my companies ide and these need to be deep inside its directory structure. And I want to make it as easy as possible for everyone, so they must only specify the root path for their ide.
I've copied the WixUIMinimal file from their official repo and wanted adjust the INSTALLFOLDER path afterwards but it just installs everything in DLC (root path of ide)
Path where the files should be installed to:

> DLC\oeide\eclipse\plugins\com.openedge.pdt.extensibility.user_1.0.0

This is my wxs for the directory

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir" ComponentGuidGenerationSeed="{51AAB846-6A74-404E-8B4A-4CAA019978C8}">
            <Directory Id="DLC" Name="OpenEdge">
                <Directory Id="oeide" Name="oeide">
                    <Directory Id="eclipse" Name="eclipse">
                        <Directory Id="plugins" Name="plugins">
                            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="com.openedge.pdt.extensibility.user_1.0.0">

                            </Directory>
                        </Directory>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
```

```
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
```